# Android httpclient.execute return 404 in the second call?

Tags: android, httpclient

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

//this return OK
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.xxx.com/pageA");
String response = httpClient.execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler());

//this return 404 error
HttpGet request2 = new HttpGet("http://www.xxx.com/pageB");
String response2 = httpClient.execute(request2, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

Why?
How can I execute http method for more than one page in the same function?

In fact, pageA is a login page, pageB is what i want.
If get pageA only, it's OK (both in brower and in source code);
If get pageB only, it returns 302 (transfer to login page);
If get pageA and then get pageB in browser, it's OK.
If get pageA and then get pageB in source code (like above), an exception will
 occur, and http status code is 404 (not 302).

(i test these code in android 4.1 jellybean)

Comment: What happens if you visit these pages in this order in the browser?

Comment: Use fiddler to check if the pageB is actually returning anything (http://fiddler2.com/)